# "Find all references" to a method in Spyder

Tags: python, ide, spyder

In Visual Studio I can right-click a function and find all instances where it is called.

How do I do the equivalent in Spyder?

Comment: Looks like you can't: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/spyderlib/qyUyzLNZXsw

Comment: Have you looked at PyCharm? In there you can right-click on a function and choose `find usages`. It's a nice IDE from https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/